# Perl on MacOS X 10.6.2: GDBM_File missing, how to install or work around?

Tags: perl, macos, cpan

When I need a Perl module, I typically use CPAN. It works fine. But not this time.

I want to use MARC::Charset, but this one uses GDBM_File, and I can't seem to install GDBM_File from CPAN.

CPAN finds it all right, but trying to install it, it starts installing the full Perl 5.10.1 distribution.

MARC::Charset is a rather old module, so there should be a way to use it from some common Perl version (Mac OS X 10.6.2 has 5.10.0 and 5.8.9 by default).

While installing the full blow Perl 5.10.1 is not an option, modifying MARC::Charset to stop using GDBM_File might be one. What would be the best course of action to do so?

This last option might also be the only one. googling GDBM_File uncovers a few items that suggest that gdbm is not even available on the Mac. Those items typically went over my head though.

While I don't expect a silver bullet, somebody may have a pointer or two on where I should start.

After all, MARC::Charset only does character transliteration to/from the marc8 char set, which unfortunately, iconv doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546192/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-that-is-in-the-latest-perl-without-installing-th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GDBM_File`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DAPM/perl-5.10.1/ext/GDBM_File/GDBM_File.pm) is a [core Perl module](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/CPAN/misc/cpan-faq.html#Where_find_GDBM_file).  This is why its trying to upgrade your Perl to latest version when you install this module.

It seems Mac OS X doesn't come with [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/) and therefore haven't built and included the necessary modules with any of its provided development languages. And this seems to have been the case [for quite some time](http://www.google.com/search?q=macosx+gdbm+missing).

So your first obstacle is the install/compile GDBM.  MacPorts does provide a [package](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/gdbm/Portfile).

`GDBM_File` is a XS module so you will have to compile it.  The Perl 5.10.0 `GDBM_File code` can be found [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RGARCIA/perl-5.10.0/ext/GDBM_File/).

BTW: [`MARC::Charset`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MARC-Charset/) only switched to `GDBM_File` at version [1.1](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ESUMMERS/MARC-Charset-1.1/lib/MARC/Charset/Table.pm) (latest version).  The previous version [1.0](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ESUMMERS/MARC-Charset-1.0/lib/MARC/Charset/Table.pm) used [`SDBM_File`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.0/ext/SDBM_File/SDBM_File.pm) which does come with Perl on Mac OS X (though haven't personally tested it works).

So you may find downloading [previous version of MARC::Charset](http://search.cpan.org/~esummers/MARC-Charset-1.0/) a better option to try.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatves: fix MARC::Charset so it doesn't need GDBM_File, or build your own Perl.

Honestly, building your own Perl is probably faster and safer. If you've never installed Perl before, I recommend you use MacPorts (http://macports.org), which will install it in /opt/local/bin/perl. You can then use "/opt/local/bin/cpan MARC::Charset" to install the module you need.

MacPorts doesn't by default build a threaded Perl - I know there's woojy-woojy on the install to do that, but I'm allergic to threads from my initial exposure to them and have never bothered to figure out what it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, requiring my customer to build and install a full distribution of Perl is not an option.
Additionally, it seems that wouldn't even be enough as gdbm is not installed on MacOS X.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved the problem by using the previous version of MARC::Charset. The previous version did not use GDBM_File but another facility. That was the only change between the versions, and the reason for the change was not stated.

Using the previous version fixed everything.

Comment: I am glad you resolved the issue but don't you think your answer above would be better served as a comment under my answer? :(

Comment: Yep you are right. I bumped your answer and tagged it as correct.